# Different result on devmachine and buildserver with ASP.NET (MVC 1)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, msbuild, build-server

We have a .NET 3.5/ASP.NET MVC 1 solution. Everything works great on the developer machines but after that build starts on the build server we get:

*"Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls."*

For example

```
<error code="ASPPARSE" file="/temp/Views/Account/ChangePasswordSuccess.aspx" line="4" column="0" timeStamp="10/10/2011 01:25:46">
    <![CDATA[Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls.]]>
</error>
```

Same ASP.NET MVC, same .NET. Visual Studio 2008 is **not** installed on the buildserver.

Any idea?

**Environment**

- Build server: CC.NET 1.6
- OS: Windows 2003 R2 SP2
- IIS 6

Comment: What are the specs for the build server i.e. OS & IIS versions

Comment: Once I faced this problem - it was due to lowercase-ed *asp:content* and changed it to *asp:Content*.

Comment: Do you have MvcBuildViews turned on for your project for building on the dev machine?

Comment: @boj: This is a long shot, but could it be this? http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/09/compiling-mvc-views-in-a-build-environment.aspx

Comment: @PaulT.: bingo, build fixed (it was false in Debug but true in Release mode). But what if I want to build views? I followed Hector's link but this method (as far I see) is already implemented in our cproj file.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. You build server likely builds a prod build, visual studio likely builds a dev build. The security restrictions and other configurations for these are likely different.

In visual studio, switch the build target off of debug and see if it still happens

Comment: Yes, PaulT's comment pointed to this problem too and its solved. So view compilation is off now - but what if I want (I do:) turn it on?

Answer (score 0):

That must be failing on the developer's machine, just that it does while trying to show the corresponding view / not while building it.

Have the developer build with it turned on, and locate the view that's failing the build.

**Update:** actually, I didn't pay close attention to the message, it is very likely you just have a page that uses a master page and has content Outside the content controls.

Answer (score 0):

As i have seen according to your message there may some layout related problem in your page. which generates some html contents at run time...

have look on this asp.net forum post.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1251873.aspx/1

as Munim Abdul said, it may be possible in that way but i do not think it is the issue with an experienced  person like you..

I have faced this error when i was learning sharepoint and in normal asp.net applications..

search out.. may be this will help you little bit..